# copy a file in ant based on condition

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant, jar

I have to copy a file if a property is set in ant target, but I always get an error for this code:

```
<condition property="component.is.x">
  <equals arg1="${COMPONENT_ID}" arg2="x" />
</condition>
<target name="copyschemaparamsfile" if="sql.file.present" >
  <if>
    <equals arg1="${component.is.x}" arg2="true" />
    <then>
      <copy file="${in.root}/schema/${COMPONENT_ID}-schema.sql"
            tofile="${tmp.dir}/${COMPONENT_ID}/x/schema/schema.sql" 
            failonerror="false" />
    </then>
    <else>
      <copy file="${inf.root}/schema/${COMPONENT_ID}-schema.sql"
            tofile="${tmp.dir}/${COMPONENT_ID}/${COMPONENT_ID}/schema/schema.sql" failonerror="false" />
    </else>
  </if>
</target>
```

**Error is**:

```
Ant could not find the task or a class this task relies upon.
This is common and has a number of causes; the usual
    solutions are to read the manual pages then download and
    install needed JAR files, or fix the build file:
     - You have misspelt 'if'.
       Fix: check your spelling.
     - The task needs an external JAR file to execute
         and this is not found at the right place in the classpath.
       Fix: check the documentation for dependencies.
       Fix: declare the task.
     - The task is an Ant optional task and the JAR file and/or libraries
         implementing the functionality were not found at the time you
         yourself built your installation of Ant from the Ant sources.
       Fix: Look in the ANT_HOME/lib for the 'ant-' JAR corresponding to the
         task and make sure it contains more than merely a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
         If all it contains is the manifest, then rebuild Ant with the needed
         libraries present in ${ant.home}/lib/optional/ , or alternatively,
         download a pre-built release version from apache.org
     - The build file was written for a later version of Ant
       Fix: upgrade to at least the latest release version of Ant
     - The task is not an Ant core or optional task
         and needs to be declared using <taskdef>.
     - You are attempting to use a task defined using
        <presetdef> or <macrodef> but have spelt wrong or not
       defined it at the point of use

    Remember that for JAR files to be visible to Ant tasks implemented
    in ANT_HOME/lib, the files must be in the same directory or on the
    classpath
```

I am always getting above error when I execute. Can someone please suggest how to check for a parameter and copy from one directory to other within an ant target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant `<if/>` is part of **Ant-Contrib**.  To use, follow the directions on the [**Ant-Contrib Tasks installation page**](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/):

> (1) Copy ant-contrib-0.3.jar to the lib directory of your Ant
>   installation. If you want to use one of the tasks in your own project,
>   add the lines

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

> to your build file.
>
> (2) Keep ant-contrib-0.3.jar in a separate location. You now have to
>   tell Ant explicitly where to find it (say in /usr/share/java/lib):

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/lib/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your response. I have done the same as 1)(1) Copy ant-contrib-0.3.jar to the lib directory of your Ant installation. If you want to use one of the tasks in your own project, add the lines

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
to your build file. but the error is still the same.

Comment: The Ant-Contrib JAR file is not being found.  For example, you may have put it in the `lib/` dir of an ant installation other than the one you're invoking.  Carefully check that along with each of the suggestions in the error message, which is unusually comprehensive.  If all of that fails, try the other (2) approach.